# Accessing secrets locally on Next.js/NOW for SSR and API routes

Tags: node.js, reactjs, environment-variables, next.js, vercel

Trying to use secrets locally with a `Next.js`/`NOW`-hosted site.

These are secrets I only want made available to `SSR` pages and `API` functions (not browser-rendered components).

Contrary to [Zeit's documentation](https://zeit.co/docs/v2/serverless-functions/env-and-secrets/#during-local-development), the secrets only seem to work if they're stored in `.env.build`. If they're stored in `.env` they show up as `undefined`.

In other words, this works:

`.env.build`

```
SECRET_KEY="2039usdljkhfklsjdfjaops9dfi09"
```

`now.json`

```
{
  "build": {
    "env": {
      "SECRET_KEY": "@secret-key"
    }
  }
}
```

This does not:

`.env`

```
SECRET_KEY="2039usdljkhfklsjdfjaops9dfi09"
```

`now.json`

```
{
  "env": {
    "SECRET_KEY": "@secret-key"
  }
}
```

Am I missing something?

My fear is that secrets put into `build` will be "built" into the site, i.e., publicly available. Am I misunderstanding the word "build?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was fixed by logging into zeit.co, going to my app's project settings, and choosing `Other` for my `Framework Preset`. It has previously been set to `Next`.

After making that change my local environment variables began showing up in `process.env` when I ran `now dev`.

This seems to be a quirk of `now 17.x`. Downgrading to `now 16.7.3` also fixed the issue. Hopefully this gets fixed soon!